# multiple points for x value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot my data in a plot similar to attached. I can not overcome the problem to have 3 points for each DB. So basically they are overlapping and I would like to move them a bit so it is more visible. I was thinking about using some grouping? This is a part of my data, I would like to see how membr_perc increase/decrease due to early/mid/late stage for each DB and compare base on the type.

```
     type  name   para length    DB replicate membr_perc
   <fctr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <chr>      <dbl>
 1      wt    PC [32:1]     32     1     early  0.2927746
 2     shc    PC [32:1]     32     1     early  0.3506922
 3      wt    PC [32:1]     32     1     early  0.2258272
 4     shc    PC [32:1]     32     1     early  0.3523230
 5      wt    PC [32:1]     32     1     early  0.2654483
 6     shc    PC [32:1]     32     1     early  0.3658814
 7     shc    PC [34:1]     34     1       mid  0.7681123
 8     shc    PC [34:1]     34     1       mid  0.7677175
 9     shc    PC [34:1]     34     1       mid  0.7474835
 10     wt    PC [34:1]     34     1      late  0.3050501
 11     wt    PC [34:1]     34     1      late  0.3215530
 12     wt    PC [34:1]     34     1      late  0.3123021
```

This is the formula I use:

```
ggplot(early_pc, aes(x = DB, y= membr_perc, col=type, shape = replicate,
                     group=interaction(type, replicate))) + geom_point()
```

A sketch of the desired plot:

[image]

Comment: Your example plot has squares (?) and shaded regions (?) and an x-axis with multiple values (?). How do those relate to your data? I don't understand what you are after. Are you just looking for `geom_jitter()`?

Comment: wow, awesome! Thank you! That is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
early_pc$replicate <- factor(early_pc$replicate, c('early', 'mid', 'late'))

ggplot(early_pc, aes(x = replicate, y = membr_perc, fill = type)) + 
  geom_jitter(size = 3, shape = 21, width = 0.2, alpha = 0.7) +
  facet_grid(~DB)
```

Gives:

[image]